# Conservation of linear momentum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws

Are there any restrictions to conservation of momentum of a system, or is it applicable in all cases?

Comment: [A simple Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=conservation+of+momentum) will find you [this description on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum#Conservation) and this seems both clear and easy to understand. Can you extend your question to indicate what aspects of this aren't clear or specifically what additional information you are seeking?

Answer (score 1):

When you consider a closed system, *ie.* one that don't exchange matter and isn't acted on by external forces, the momentum is conserved: indeed, the Second Law of Newton states that

$$ \frac{d\textbf{p}}{dt} = \sum_i \textbf{F}_i$$

but, with no external force, this becomes

$$ \textbf{p} = \textbf{Constant}$$

However, when you consider a system that is acted on by external forces, or one whose mass changes, momentum isn't conserved anymore.